# Access Adreno GPU inside a Docker container

Tags: docker, gpu, qualcomm

I recently bought this edge computer: https://www.thundercomm.com/product/eb5-edge-ai-box/

I has an Adreno 650 GPU.

I'm using SNPE (Snap Dragon Neural Processing Engine) to run AI models on it. Outside a Docker container I'm able to access the GPU normally. Inside it I can't.

To know if the GPU is available or not, SNPE SDK has a CLI command called `snpe-platform-validator`.

Running it outside the Docker:

```
snpe-platform-validator --runtime gpu --debug
```

I receive:

```
PF_VALIDATOR: DEBUG: Calling PlatformValidator->setRuntime
PF_VALIDATOR: DEBUG: Calling PlatformValidator->RuntimeCheck
PF_VALIDATOR: DEBUG: Building and running a simple Vector addition gpu program.
Unit Test on the runtime GPU: Passed.
SNPE is supported for runtime GPU on the device.
PF_VALIDATOR: DEBUG: Calling PlatformValidator->IsRuntimeAvailable
Runtime GPU Prerequisites: Present.
```

Inside the Docker. After installing OpenCL with:

```
apt install -y ocl-icd-opencl-dev
```

and running the same command as previously, I've got the following:

```
PF_VALIDATOR: DEBUG: Calling PlatformValidator->setRuntime
PF_VALIDATOR: DEBUG: Calling PlatformValidator->RuntimeCheck
PF_VALIDATOR: ERROR: Failed to query OpenCL platform.
Unit Test on the runtime GPU: Failed.
SNPE is NOT supported for runtime GPU on the device.
PF_VALIDATOR: DEBUG: Calling PlatformValidator->IsRuntimeAvailable
Runtime GPU Prerequisites: Present.
Error in saving the results root
```

Anyone has experience with Qualcomm device or had experience on accessing GPU hardware inside a Docker container?

Installing OpenCL drivers inside the Docker container.

Comment: Did you have any luck with this?!! I encountered exactly same issue. Not able to access GPU from inside docker container.

Comment: @MsA not yet. I'm still facing the same issue.

Comment: I had some success, but now getting [this](https://developer.qualcomm.com/forum/qdn-forums/software/adreno-gpu-sdk/68387) error.

Comment: @MsA how you accessed the GPU inside the Docker?

Comment: Run your docker container with following options: `-v /data:/data -v /usr:/usr --device=/dev/ --privileged`.